# domination in directed graphs with transitive tournaments

Tags: graph-theory

Given a digraph on n vertices, suppose the subgraph induced by any k of its vertices contains a transitive k-vertex tournament as a subgraph. Does the digraph have a dominating set consisting of l vertices? For which smallest k, if any, is the minimum such l=l(n,k) independent of n?

Comment: To comment, over the family of all digraphs on n vertices with the tournament property for fixed k, what is the maximum value of the minimum such l=l(n,k), i.e. the maximum value of the domination number, and for which k does it become constant as n increases?